# can i bin a numerical data basis on the quantiles or boxplot

Tags: python

I want to crate bin or bucket on a numerical column basis on the quantiles/(boxplot). Below is the sample data:

```
amount={'amount':[23,34,56,78,65,54,67,87,90,120,25,68,90,23,45,68,79,23,56,56,76,200,214,321]}
df=pd.DataFrame(amount,columns=['amount'])
df.describe()
```

Comment: [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) ?

Comment: You have `pd.qcut`, for `pd.cut` you have to specify the bins @sushanth